apostrophe in the path name of python file
I am trying to run a python script which is saved on OneDrive. The name of OneDrive is set by my organisation and so I cannot change it.
My problem is when I try to run any script it fails because of the apostrophe. I click on the arrow in vscode to run the file, which results in this bash command: /usr/bin/python3 /Users/username/the organisation's name/Desktop/scripts/mycode.py
In the terminal it just says quote> and it looks like it's waiting for input. When I click run again then the second apostrophe closes the quote and I get the output
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/username/the organisations name/Desktop/scripts/mycode.py

/Users/username/theorganisationsname/Desktop/scripts/mycode.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The only way it works is if I type in the terminal: /usr/bin/python3 [path] and use the esc character for the apostrophy, but it's not a sustainable solution. I could do an alias I guess, but I'd need to do that for all scripts I have on onedrive. I can also store files locally, not on OneDrive, but I don't like the idea of being defeated by an apostrophe.
Weirdly when I tried to replicate the problem on my laptop (I created a path /Users/username/Desktop/Code/Julia's folder/test.py) the code runs fine. The bash command is /usr/bin/python3 "/Users/username/Desktop/Code/Julia's folder/test.py" - the path is in quotation marks. This doesn't happen when I run the file saved on onedrive.

Added info:

The example path should actually be: /Users/username/CloudStorage/the organisation's name/Desktop/scripts/mycode.py to be more precise. I notices that when I change the path in vscode so it doesn't include "CloudStorage" then everything is working (see my answer below for detail).
I also created a matlab file /Users/username/CloudStorage/the organisation's name/Desktop/scripts/test.m it runs fine with the original path (not sure if that indicates anything).


Try putting the complete path name in double quotes.

@OldBoy I run the file by clicking the triangle in vscode. I don't type the path to the file I want to run, so can't put quotes in it.

What does your launch.json look like?

This sounds like a problem with OneDrive or the interaction between OneDrive and VSCode, based on your inability to reproduce it locally. The error message looks like special characters like spaces and the apostrophe are simply being dropped, rather than properly escaped. (The fact that the same path is represented two different ways in the error message is suspicious.)

I just tested this by adding escaped quotes around the path names in the tasks.json settings, and it appears to work. Although I do not have a path with a quote character in it to test fully.

@OldBoy I don't know what those json files are. Which path you want be to put in quotes? The OneDrive directory, or each specific .py file on OneDrive?

I don't know vsc, and if the problem is how to perform something by clicking to somewhere in vsc, this question is not about programming and should be asked at i.e. [su]. In the meantime, I suggest that you simply write a shell function or script which you call for the command line. Once this works, you can think on how to turn this into something which you can click to run it.

@user1934428 @OldBoy I think my best bet would be to figure out how to access the folder without the CloudStorage component (see my edits to the question)

Could it be that OneDrive, in an attempt to be clever, changes the name of the file somewhat, when you upload it? In this case, this is unrelated to python or bash. What do you see when you do a ls -R /Users/username/CloudStorage

My previous test was on Windows which worked. However trying to modify the path in my Linux system does not seem to work. Typically when using this sort of package, it is almost impossible to find out what is going on under the covers. I need to consult Microsoft on this.

@user1934428 I get an error saying this directory doesn't exist. Same thing if I do cd /Users/username/CloudStorage. When I open the OneDrive in finder (it's added to the window, on left, under 'Locations') then the path is displayed as OneDrive-organisation's name/Desktop... but when I click on the file with the option key (mac) and select 'copy as pathname' then I get the full /Users/username/CloudStorage/the organisation's name/Desktop/scripts/mycode.py. Which is the same that vscode (and MatLab) sees when I open the file location through their file browsers. Both display this path ^

@OldBoy I have a mac, and I suspect that the issue is how OneDrive is accessed on mac. When I installed the OneDrive app and logged into my account I clicked 'add to finder' and that added it to /Users/username/ folder. I am not sure why CloudStorage appears sometimes

Sorry, but I have never done any development on Macs so cannot test anything, let alone find an answer.

I have a Mac, but I don't use OneDrive. But if you copy the pathname and get /Users/username/CloudStorage, and ls tells you that the directory does not exist, there is something odd going on. Since your first step is to see the directory from a shell, this is something to research. Leave out VSC, which just unnecessarily complicates things, and do everything from Terminal.app. Also, I suggest that you ask this problem at [apple.se]. Add a Screenshot from your Terminal.app, which demonstrates that the ls command indeed produces the error message you mentioned.

Partial solution: I initially opened the file through the OneDrive I had added to finder (there was an option when logging into Onedrive to add to finder, so I just used the path(?) it created to access the contents including when I opened it in vscode).
So in vscode the path at the top was /Users/username/Library/CloudStorage/the organisation's name/Desktop/scripts/mycode.py. I clicked on Library and manually chose the organisation's name (skipping the CloudStorage bit) and the rest. Then the code run fine. Leaving this here in case someone has a similar problem.


Okay this actually is not a sustainable solution either. I would have to do this for every file I open in vscode separately. If I use the filebrowser/finder when I click 'open folder' then it will default to this path. Somehow the presence of CloudStorage determined whether bash will wrap the path in quotes or not. So I guess it's more of a OneDrive/ vscode question?

Try the solution with a backslash containing '.
python3 path/organization\ \'\ s/hello.py

in my bash console this works fine

I cannot edit my organisations name, and I don't want to run the file by typing the command in the terminal. As I have written in my question it also works fine for me if I type the path in bash and add escape character. I just didn't want to have to do that.
